# How are the bools in my while loop affecting the loop?

Tags: python-3.x, tic-tac-toe

I'm learning Python and I built a TicTacToe game. I'm now writing unit tests and improving my code. I was advised to make a while loop in my turn function and use the following bools, but I don't know why. I can see some reason to why this makes sense, but because of how new I am I couldn't even explain why it makes any sense to me. Can someone explain why this would make more sense than another combination of bools?

```
    print(TTTGame.player + "'s TURN!")
    print('pick a number 1 through 9')
    position = int(input()) - 1
    valid = False<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<False
    while not valid:<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<Not
      try: 
        position = int(input('pick a spot'))
      except (ValueError):
        print('pick a number 1 though 9')
        x = TTTGame.board[position]
        if x == '-':
          TTTGame.board[position] = TTTGame.player
        else:
          print('Cant Go There!')        
          TTTGame.board[position] = TTTGame.player
          valid = True<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<True
```

Comment: "Can someone explain why this would make more sense than another combination of bools?" What other way do you propose to do this? It is a very good exercise to implement the same thing two different ways. Then compare the pros and cons of each

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you provided I would have to try to work backwards to create a worse example, and without seeing what you did initially that may cause more confusion than it would help. A fair number of the things I mention are subjective to each developer, but the principles tend to be commonly agreed upon to some degree (especially in python).

That being said I will try to explain why this pattern is optimal:

1. Intuitiveness: When reading this code and looking from the outside I can tell that you are doing validation, primarily this is because just reading the code as plain English I see you are assuming the input to be invalid (valid == False) and won't leave the loop until it has been validated (valid == True). Even without the additional context of knowing it was a tic-tac-toe game I can immediately tell by reading the code this is the case.
2. Speed: In terms of how long it takes to complete this function, it will terminate as soon as the input is valid as opposed to some other ways of doing this that require more than one check.
3. Pythonic: In the python community there is an emphasis on 'pythonic' code, basically this means that there are ways of doing things that are common across various types of python code. In this case there are many patterns of validating input (using for loops, terminating conditions, seperate functions etc.), but again because of how this is written I would be able to debug it without having to necessarily know your whole codebase. This also means if you see a similar chunk of code in a large project, you are more likely to recognize what's happening. It follows the principles of the [zen of python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#id2) in that you are being explicit, while maintaining readability, errors are not passing silently and you are keeping it simple.